# Issues with rsync.synchronized in SaltStack Not Syncing Directory Content

Tags: rsync, salt-stack

I'm trying to use rsync.synchronized in SaltStack to sync a directory from master to a minion. Here's the SLS configuration I've used:

```yaml
sync_pyenv:
  rsync.synchronized:
    - source: /home/user/test/
    - force: True
```

Executing `salt 'test01' state.sls sync_files saltenv=dev` results in the following error:

```yaml
rsync: change_dir "/home/user/test" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23)
```

After ensuring the `test` directory exists on `test01` and tweaking the SLS to include `- prepare: True`, the state runs successfully but doesn't sync the contents of `/home/user/test/`. The output indicates a successful run but shows "total size is 0".

I also tried adding `- name: /home/user/test/` to the SLS, but it didn't resolve the issue. The directory and its contents are not being synced to the minion. I want to sync the `test` directory and its files without moving it to the Salt `file_roots`. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified a remote server for either the source or target. Nor have you specified a target directory. Thus it is running this command on `test01`:

```bash
rsync --archive --force /home/user/test/ sync_pyenv
```

The correct state would be:

```yaml
sync_pyenv:
  rsync.synchronized:
    - name: /home/user/test/
    - source: mysaltmaster:/home/user/test/
    - prepare: true
```

You will still need to have set up SSH access for root from the minion to the master for this to work.

If the source files are on the master, you should probably mount them on the fileserver (i.e. with `file_roots`) and use [`file.recurse`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.recurse):

```yaml
sync_pyenv:
  file.recurse:
    - name: /home/user/test/
    - source: salt://test_data/pyenv
```

Or, recreate the pyenv using states to set it up from scratch, rather than copying from a random user's home directory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Based on the official examples, I thought I wouldn't need to consider the rsync server. I am now planning to use file.recurse to synchronize some files. As for pyenv, I might need some other methods because using file synchronization seems too inefficient.

```yaml
/opt/user-backups:
rsync.synchronized:
- source: /home
- force: True
```